# how to adjust dataloader and make a new dataloader?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, dataloader

let say I have a data loader of cifar10 
if I want to remove some value from the dataloader and make a new dataloader
how should I do it?

```
def load_data_cifar10(batch_size=128,test=False):
    if not test:
        train_dset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='/mnt/3CE35B99003D727B/input/pytorch/data', train=True,
                                                download=True, transform=transform)
    else:
        train_dset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='/mnt/3CE35B99003D727B/input/pytorch/data', train=False,
                                               download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    print("LOAD DATA, %d" % (len(train_loader)))
    return train_loader
```

Comment: What do you want to change about the data loader?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) dataset. This takes another dataset as input as well as a list of indices to construct a new dataset. Say you want the first 1000 entries, then you could do

```
subset_train_dset = torch.utils.data.Subset(train_dset, range(1000))
```

You can also construct datasets composed of multiple datasets using [`ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) dataset, or combinations of `ConcatDataset` and `Subset` to build whatever you like

```
frankenstein_dset = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset((
    torch.utils.data.Subset(dset1, range(1000)),
    torch.utils.data.Subset(dset2, range(100)))
```

In your case you would need to either look into the implementation details to determine which indices to keep, or you could write some code to iterate through the original dataset first and save all the indicies you want to keep, then define a `Subset` with the appropriate indices.

Comment: subset_train_dset.dataset.data.shape. is not working with real dataloader. and for idx,(img,target) in enumerate(dataloader):
spit the error : TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: subset_train_dset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataloader, range(1000))
for idx,(img,target) in enumerate(subset_train_dset):
    print(idx ,':' ,img.shape)

Comment: datasets don't generally have a `.data` member (that's for specific datasets). Read the docs for more info, but the only things a dataset is required to implement is `__getitem__` and `__len__`. So if you want the length of a dataset object you must use `len(dataset)` for a general solution.