# Given a torch DataLoader, how can I create another DataLoader which is a subset

Tags: python, pytorch, subset, pytorch-dataloader

Given an torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader (let's say stored as variable `data_loader_original`), how can I create a new torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader which contains a subset of `data_loader_original`?

I've seen this post [how to adjust dataloader and make a new dataloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412287/how-to-adjust-dataloader-and-make-a-new-dataloader), but I don't want to take a subset of the dataset directly (i.e. I don't want to use torch.utils.data.Subset).  Instead I want something like

`data_loader_subset = create_subset_data_loader(data_loader_original)`

or

`data_loader_subset = data_loader_ogirinal[:size_of_subset]`

These are just examples to help illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how can you split the subset, for the simple version, the snipcode below may help:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

bs = 50
shuffle = False
num_workers = 0
dataset = torch_dataset()
data_loader_original = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=bs, shuffle=shuffle)

def create_subset_data_loader(loader, size_of_subset):
    count = 0
    for data in loader:
        yield data
        if count == size_of_subset:
            break
        count+=1

size_of_subset = 10

for epoch in range(epochs):
   for data in create_subset_data_loader(data_loader_original, size_of_subset):
      # processing
```

Comment: Good idea.  I'll give a little time to see what other answers show up.  If this is best, I'll mark as the solution. thanks.

Comment: I just edited the answer, the last code could only work with one epoch